# iocage jail with different subnet cannot ping network

Tags: freebsd, truenas

I have a FreeBSD 11.1 iocage jail on a different subnet than the host and I want it to reach other hosts on the same subnet as the host.

```
Host IP: 192.168.0.10 (interface re0)
Default GW: 192.168.0.1
JAIL IP: 10.1.1.10
```

I have configured:

```
iocage set ip4_addr="re0|10.1.1.10/24" myjail
iocage set defaultrouter="192.168.0.1" myjail
```

From the jail I can ping the host 192.168.0.10, but cannot ping another hosts on the same network as the host, for example 192.168.0.1 (the gateway).

Any hint?.

Answer (score 0):

All host in this network must know about route way to 10.1.1.10.
On your main GW add path to 10.1.1.0/24 via 192.168.0.10.
Or on specified host just add:

```
route add 10.1.1.0/24 gateway 192.168.0.10
```